# Reservation between two users

Tags: centos, slurm

I have two user u1 and u2 and 4 nodes.

I would like to know how to create a reservation for u2 to take only 1 node. But if u1 wants to use the 4 nodes and they are available (if u2 is not using a node), he can take them.

I tried that but it does not do everything I want:

```
scontrol create reservation StartTime=now Duration=infinite NodeCnt=1 User=u2
```

I think we have to use the partition option but I do not really understand how to use it.

Comment: Partitions are queues; you can create two different partitions/queues, e.g. `singlenode` and `allnodes`, and associate `u1` to `singlenode`, and `u2` to `allnodes`.

Comment: Hello, thank for your reply, how can I create his partitions, which command should I use?

Comment: See the link in my answer below. If this solves your problem, tick the answer as accepted, on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to use partitions.

Since there are quite a lot of steps, which may depend on your specific configuration, I link the official quickstart documentation for slurm admins: https://slurm.schedmd.com/quickstart_admin.html